# SQL SERVER The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

SQL SERVER 2008

i have a data and i am trying to do pivot.
while running the below code encountered with error as

```
The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Sel NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @GENERIC NVARCHAR(MAX)





SET @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Description]) 
            FROM STAGING_TEMP 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
SET @Sel = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Description]) + 
' AS DESC'+CAST(row_number () over (order by ([Description])) as varchar(250))
            FROM STAGING_TEMP 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''); 



SET @SQL = N'
SELECT DISTINCT [Generic Name], '+ @Sel+N'
FROM STAGING_TEMP
    pivot
    (
      MAX(Description) For Description IN ('+ @Cols + N')

    ) P';

EXECUTE( @SQL);
```

When i run the individual segment of code i came to know the below code produce 40000 desc value which has 35k Duplicate value AS Different DESC.

```
SET @Sel = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Description]) + 
' AS DESC'+CAST(row_number () over (order by ([Description])) as varchar(250))
            FROM STAGING_TEMP 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
```

is there any way to handle such scenario. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.  The maximum number of columns in a `SELECT` statement is 4,096 (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)).

You would have a column for each value in the `IN` list.  Even if you fixed one problem, you would just face another.

Comment: I am little confused when The Generic Name which has highest number of description is 50, how it is generated DESC 40000

Comment: The Generic Name which has highest number of description is 50, all other Generic Name has less than 50 description

Comment: @akhrotk . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  This addresses the question that you did ask, but you seem to have other problems.  I would guess that the number of total descriptions is over 4,096 -- simplified sample data and desired results would help the new question.